# MySQL - Insert triggers update on other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables :

[image]

After each INSERT on the Sales table, it needs to trigger an update to the table Sales_DAY. This table contains each Sale per Seller, per Product, and per day.

The amount on the Sales_DAY needs to be incremented each time there's an entry in Sales that corresponds to one in Sales_DAY table.

I thought about something like this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON `Sales` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
       UPDATE Sales_DAY
           SET amount = amount + NEW.amount
           WHERE commercial_id = NEW.commercial_id
           AND produit_id = NEW.produit_id
           AND date = DATE(NEW.date);
END;
```

As I've never created any trigger, I'd like to know if that's the right way to make it work.

Comment: Yes it's correct way to do same things.

Comment: You may also need insert logic.

Comment: What if `Sales_DAY` has no matching value ? Are you supposed to make a new entry in that case ?

Comment: Ha yes, I forgot that case. I need to check that, and make the first insert if that is the case.